# How to implement singleton design pattern in C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

How to implement singleton design pattern in C#?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx if you really have to - but ideally don't...

Comment: really dude, just ask Google.. first result

Comment: No effort at all, downvoted.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In singleton pattern, a class can only have one instance and provides access point to it globally.

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
     private static readonly Singleton _instance = new Singleton();
}
```

Comment: you may add a property?

Comment: should also have Private constructor